# Connectivity issue - tcpdump reports ping a success, ping itself does not

Tags: ip, ping, tcpdump, icmp, arp

I am having some connectivity issues. The arp table is not populated even if the arp request are successfully transferred on the wire. Which leads to unsuccessfully ping. When I add a arp entry manually, tcpdump shows replies but not ping itself.

Ping packets got reply in tcpdump but not in ping.

```
Pinging 12.12.12.10 from 12.12.12.7
Ping Screen:
From 12.12.12.7 icmp_seq=594 Destination Host Unreachable
From 12.12.12.7 icmp_seq=595 Destination Host Unreachable
From 12.12.12.7 icmp_seq=596 Destination Host Unreachable
From 12.12.12.7 icmp_seq=598 Destination Host Unreachable
From 12.12.12.7 icmp_seq=599 Destination Host Unreachable




Tcpdump output:

08:18:38.117478 IP 12.12.12.7 > 12.12.12.10: ICMP echo request, id 64559,      seq 197, length 64
08:18:38.118852 IP 12.12.12.10 > 12.12.12.7: ICMP echo reply, id 64559, seq 197, length 64
08:18:39.117471 IP 12.12.12.7 > 12.12.12.10: ICMP echo request, id 64559, seq 198, length 64
08:18:39.119015 IP 12.12.12.10 > 12.12.12.7: ICMP echo reply, id 64559, seq 198, length 64
```

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue too, could you check your firewall policy is set up right?